# How can I filter data using regex in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, nestjs

I'm new to Elasticsearch. Have been exploring this recently.

I want to get all the data from elastic search for a table. But at the same time I need only thoose data in which "phoneNumber" field is not a valid phone number. How may I achieve this?

Data structure:

```
{
            "_index": "test_session3",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "f76adaaf-23e0-455a-9d74-6e2335b60bd9",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
                "phoneNumber": "12424242424",
                "utilizationFeeType": "flat",
                "chargingEndTime": "2023-06-07T04:56:37.421Z",
                "invFee": 22.22,
                "sessionStartTime": "2023-06-07T04:56:38.340Z",
                "chargerId": "584eb6b8-4f69-4628-b94a-3ea5c49e14bc",
                "plugStatus": "connected",
                "idleEndTime": "2023-06-07T04:56:37.421Z",
                "sessionEndTime": "2023-06-07T04:56:39.108Z",
                "activeFeeType": "MinimumFee",
                "chargingStartTime": "2023-06-07T04:56:38.340Z",
                "chargingRate": 7.7,
                "createdAt": "2023-06-07T04:54:56.604Z",
                "zone": "Asia/Dhaka",
                "transactionId": 3507,
                "energyConsumed": 0,
                "updatedAt": "2023-06-07T04:56:38.340Z",
                "userId": "53753b5f-1e5f-491f-b8bb-dcd6658f6e5d",
                "sessionStatus": "ended",
                "id": "f76adaaf-23e0-455a-9d74-6e2335b60bd9",
                "chargingDuration": -919,
                "idleDuration": 0,
                "sessionDuration": -919,
                "totals": 12.07,
                "idleFee": 0,
                "idleTime": "",
                "userName": "fex fo",
                "userType": "admin",
                "doubleinvFee": 22.22,
                "doubleTotals": 12.07,
                "locationId": "e3ba8172-0a8c-4c09-9f71-f074e094de9d",
                "propertyId": "a0099bbd-13aa-4c2c-a2ec-68b8d0967947",
                "companyId": "cf58acca-d7df-42b4-9555-7693d4fcc73c",
                "location": {
                    "currentPropertyId": "a0099bbd-13aa-4c2c-a2ec-68b8d0967947",
                    "currentCompanyId": "cf58acca-d7df-42b4-9555-7693d4fcc73c",
                    "title": "Lubowitz Avenue 53370812",
                    "landmark": "Southwest of the front entrance",
                    "zip": "10001",
                    "city": "New York",
                    "state": "New York",
                    "country": "US",
                    "address": "East Avenue, Rochester, NY, USA",
                    "latitude": "34.88923",
                    "longitude": "-118.13612",
                    "online": true,
                    "availableForGuest": true,
                    "status": "Active",
                    "id": "e3ba8172-0a8c-4c09-9f71-f074e094de9d",
                    "currentCompanyName": "Rich Information Technology",
                    "currentPropertyName": "East Avenue",
                    "chargersCount": 2,
                    "longitudeNum": -118.13612,
                    "latitudeNum": 34.88923,
                    "location": {
                        "lat": 34.88923,
                        "lon": -118.13612
                    }
                },
                "company": {
                    "zip": "10001",
                    "status": "Active",
                    "zohoNewComAdded": true,
                    "isDeleted": false,
                    "email": "contact@richinfotech.org",
                    "country": "US",
                    "name": "Rich Information Technology",
                    "state": "New York",
                    "city": "New York",
                    "byCreatedAt": "byCreatedAt",
                    "fileId": "15f98c05-5615-4d95-8cd6-23323668cc7f",
                    "byEmail": "byEmail",
                    "id": "cf58acca-d7df-42b4-9555-7693d4fcc73c",
                    "zohoVendorId": "4064488000000194001",
                    "phone": "1010101011",
                    "byPhone": "byPhone",
                    "website": "richinfotech.org",
                    "ein": "",
                    "createdAt": "2022-10-12T10:54:27.977Z",
                    "zohoCompanyId": "4064488000000318001",
                    "address": "Silicon Valley",
                    "byName": "byName",
                    "zohoCompanyErrorMessage": "",
                    "updatedAt": "2023-06-05T09:27:25.158Z",
                    "zohoCompanyError": false
                }
            },
            "sort": [
                1686113799108
            ]
        }
```

I want to validate data with the regex expression: /^+?[0-9]{11}$/ -> where phone number must be length of 11 and may have a leading "+'

Here is my approach:

```
 const searchFilters = {
            query: {
                bool: {
                    must: [],
                    must_not: [
                        {
                            regexp: {
                                'phoneNumber.keyword': '^\\+?[0-9]{11}$',
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                    filter: [],
                },
            },
            size: 10000,
        };

     
        const resp = await ElasticSearchHelper.search(IndexNames.SESSION, searchFilters);
        const data = resp.body?.hits?.hits;
```

But it returns empty array of data. I am expecting to have all the data where phone number is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

## Tldr;

You do not have any results because of elasticsearch's regex operator support.
In [the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/regexp-syntax.html#regexp-unsupported-operators) it is mentioned that elasticsearch regex's do not support `^` and `$`.

> Lucene’s regular expression engine does not support anchor operators, such as ^ (beginning of line) or $ (end of line). To match a term, the regular expression must match the entire string.

You will need to build another regex matching the constraint of Lucene (the search library elasticsearch is built on)

Comment: So except for the regex expression, is the approach okay? Is this how I can filter invalid phone numbers?

Comment: You will need to build another regex expression with Elasticsearch/Lucene constraints in mind.